# Javascript JSON function parsing issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

Having a strange issue where im trying to parse some JSON for use with Chart.JS .. I can console log within the function and use the array so to say as expected but outside of that function even though i have made it a Global variable the array is empty after the function runs and i print it out to the console.

```
var data = {}
const api_url = "http://localhost:5000/"
var currentPage = window.location.href
currentPage = currentPage.split("/")

currentPage = api_url + currentPage[4]

console.log(currentPage)

async function getJson() {
  const response = await fetch(currentPage);
  data = await response.json();

  console.log(data)


}


getJson()

console.log(data)
```

Comment: It looks like it might be a scoping issue. Can you replace `getJson(); console.log(data);` with `console.log(getJson())` and add `return data` to the end of `getJson`? Then let me know if it's still broken.

Comment: This is expected. It is how javascript works due to its async nature. The `console.log` at the end will be called before `getJson()` as `getJson` is an asynchronous method

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are executing an `async function` but you don't `await`.

So, instead of this:

```
getJson()
```

Use this:

```
getJson().then(_ => console.log(data))
```